# Is there any way to sort rows of a table view using a date/time? swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a messaging function in an app and I'm trying to sort the cells of a tableView based off a timestamp included with every message. I have two strings that are used to populate two different custom cells. Due to this, I can't just rearrange the contents of the string, I need to rearrange the rows themselves.

```
class messageThreadViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
       return finalItems.count
    } else {
       return finalItems2.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "message1") as! MyTableViewCellThread
      cell.messagelabel?.text = finalItems[indexPath.row]
               return cell
    } else {
       let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "message2") as! MyTableViewCellThread2
       cell2.messageLabel2?.text = finalItems2[indexPath.row]
               return cell2
    }
}
```

the two different strings are finalItems and finalitems2. I have attached an image of the app running to help get a better idea of what I'm trying to do. Let me know if I can explain it better. Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot simulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when sorting cells in tableviews, you simply sort the arrays (datasource) themselves and then call the `tableView.reloadData()` method.
To sort arrays, the best practice is

```
let sortedArray = array.filter { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp } 
// This sort with descending order, just replace '>' with '<'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am aware that this is how you'd sort the elements of an array, but I need the actual cells to be sorted rather than having all of finalItems presented on the left, then all of finalitems2 presented on the right. does that make sense?

Comment: So, if I understand, you want all the cells to be sorted by date, rather than just sorting each array?

Comment: yes, exactly. is something like that even possible?

Comment: I would then suggest adding a new property to each cell so you know if that is of finalItems of finalitems 2 and merging the two arrays into a single one. You then sort the array and then decide in which collectionView section to allocate them based on the property you added

Comment: any chance you could provide a general example of that? that sounds like it would work well for what I want to do

Comment: I thought again and I believe section is not the right way to go because if you only used section you would get the first section of only left-aligned cell and the second one of right-aligned cells. I don't if I am being clear. I think a better way to go would be using two types of custom cells- one left aligned and one right aligned so that you can alternate them.

Comment: Hi Luca, thanks for the guidance. I did eventually get it working and here's what I did: I had one prototype cell and one final sorted array that is comprised of two arrays (sent message array and received message array). After listing the final array through the prototype cell, I aligned the label to the right side of the screen if the text of the cell was included in the sent message array. I just used "if finalItems2.contains(cell.messagelabel.text!) {
            cell.messagelabel.textAlignment = .right
        } to accomplish this. Thanks again for the responses.

Comment: Happy you found a solution, sounds about right!!